# How to escape modulo in Django translation strings (ugettext_lazy)

Tags: django, django-i18n

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(_("100% of escaping problems sucks"), max_length=50)
```

The string is then threated as a python-format in gettext because it contains a modulo (%)

How do I escape it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only workaround I found to be working... and it's ugly as hell:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(_("100%(bs)s of escaping problems sucks") % {'bs': '%'}, max_length=50)
```

Comment: do i still need to use it in 2019 ?